# How to activate an asp.net core website /api after deplyment with devops releases?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm deploying an asp.net core web app to various test servers whenever updated code is pushed. It works well.

I would however like to call an endpoint on the deployed web app after release to verify that all is indeed ok.

I've got the endpoint ready -- how do I active it from the release pipeline (preferably asserting a return code of 200 ok)?

(I'm usually at Stackoverflow, apologies if this is not an appropriate serverfault question!)

BR, Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Powershell Script task, with Script Type "Inline" and just `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://<your-endpoint>` because [Invoke-WebRequest doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#examples) says (in example 7) :

> When Invoke-WebRequest encounters a non-success HTTP message (404,
>   500, etc.), it returns no output and throws a terminating error. To
>   catch the error and view the StatusCode you can enclose execution in a
>   try/catch block.

If you don't tick the box "Continue on error" in your pipeline, the pipeline will stop if this Powershell task failed.

Comment: Brilliant, and nice reference -- almost too easy! Thanks!